# Selecting record where string value begins with number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database with a table called productmanufacturers, with columns of ID, Name. I want to get all records where the Name column begins with a number.

I have tried the following, but it is messy and I am thinking too cumbersome. Is there a more reduced way of writing the query?

Current Query:

```
select * from productmanufacturers where Name like '0%' or Name like '1%' or Name like '2%' or Name like '3%' or Name like '4%' or Name like '5%' or Name like '6%' or Name like '7%' or Name like '8%' or Name like '9%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this !

```
select * from productmanufacturers where Name like '[0-9]%'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17531)

Comment: Awesome thank you. I tried that but with Regex, and then realized that REGEX was for MySql. This worked great.